# Complete the square for exponents

Tags: exponentiation

How does $\exp(2x)-2+\exp(-2x) = (\exp(x) - \exp(-x))^2$ ?

I am having trouble using complete the square.

Comment: Multiply out the RHS, keeping in mind that $\exp(x)^2=\exp(2x)$.

Comment: Say i dont know the result on RHS, so to work on LHS only?

Comment: Then I'd suggest writing $z=\exp(x)$, and observe that the LHS becomes $$z^2-2+z^{-2}=z^{-2}\cdot(z^4-2z^2+1).$$ Can you factor that last term?

Comment: z^−2 * (z^2 -1)(z^2 -1)

Comment: Right! And if you move each of those factors of $z^{-1}$ into one of the terms, and restore your original notation, what do you get?

Comment: I moved z^-2 back into a bracket, 
(1-z^-2)(z^2 -1)
however expanding yields LHS again. What is the way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute $exp(x)=a$

Write down the first two summands: $a^2-2$

*Completing the square*

To get the second binomial formula, -2 has to be -2ab. a is $exp(x)$. Thus b has to be $exp(-x)$, because $exp(x) \cdot exp(-x)=1$ . Now it is obvious, that $b^2=exp(-2x)$.

$a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2 \Rightarrow exp(2x)-2+exp(-2x)= \left( exp(x)-exp(-x) \right)^2$

Comment: @user174232 You are welcome.